# How do I access the memory of a heap allocated vector in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector, heap-memory

The array part works fine, but the vector part does not:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#define log(x) std::cout << x << "\n"

int main() {
    // array
    {
        int* array = new int[1];
        array[0] = 400;
    
        log( array[0] << "\nArray\n" );
        delete array;
    }
    
    // vector
    {
        vector<int>* vec = new vector<int>();    
        vec->push_back( 500 );
        
        log ( vec[0] << "\nVector");
        delete vec;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I make the **vector** part spit out the **500**?
My code gives me an **Error**.

Comment: `delete array;` must be `delete[] array;`

Comment: Also note that `vector<int>*` is _useless use of pointers_. `vector<int>` is just fine for use.

Comment: Don't do `new vector<int>();` ever!

Comment: `#define log(x)` is also not allowed. There is a function with the name `log` in the standard library and your macro conflicts with it. This can result in some very confusing problems. Avoid using macros at all, but if you do, make sure that you use a name that is definitively unique. In particular it shouldn't be all lower-case, because most of the standard library uses sll lower-case names.

Comment: vec[0] doesn't do what you think it does. As said try to avoid new/delete in current C++ altogether. If you somehow need to allocate memory dynamically for polymorphic objects, use std::make_unique otherwise use containers and rely on move semantics. The use of macros in C++ should also be avoided as much as you can, in C++ in a lot of case you can either write a function or a function template.

Answer (score 4):

You have to dereference pointer to vector to access its `operator[]`:

```
log( (*vec)[0] << "\nVector" );
```

But you shouldn't use `new` with `std::vector` at all. Vector already allocates memory internally to save you from having to do so, so just create the object with automatic lifetime:

```
std::vector<int> vec; 
vec.push_back(500); 
log(vec[0] << "\nVector");
```

---

Also, you have Undefined Behaviour in your array example. Things allocated with `new` must be released with `delete`, but things allocated with `new[]` must be released with `delete[]`:

```
int* array = new int[1];
array[0] = 400;
log( array[0] << "\nArray\n" );
delete[] array; // Very important!
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! First of all, when asking questions about errors in your code, please make sure to include the error messages you get from your compiler in your question, as well as details like which version of which compiler you are using etc.

Now to your question: While you *can* allocate a `std::vector` on the heap with `new`, in most cases you really shouldn't. Internally, `std::vector<int>` already does things similar to `int* array = new int[n]`, so just writing `std::vector<int> vec;` gives you the heap allocated 'array' you are looking for, which you can access with `vec[0]` after a call to `push_back`. When you do allocate the vector on the heap, you have to dereference it before indexing into it: `(*vec)[0]`.

Also when you allocate an array with `new int[N]`, you need to deallocate it with `delete[]`, not `delete`.

Comment: Your 1st paragraph should have been posted as a comment on the question, rather than part of your answer.